# Google docs forms confirmation email when someone signs up?

Tags: google-forms

When you are using google docs forms so people can sign up to an event. Is it possible to make the form send out a confirmation email when someone registers?

Answer (score 2):

**It's possible but you'll need to do a little scripting**

Sending an email after a form submission is such a common task that Google has a complete tutorial to show you how to do it.

Take a look at:

[Tutorial: Automating a Help Desk Workflow](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles/helpdesk_tutorial.html#section1)

Just keep in mind that Google does put limits on the number of emails that can be sent. The limit depends on what type of account you have (ex. Education, Business, etc).

You can check your email use relative to the limit by calling:

```
MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
```

Google Apps Scripting makes it easy to do complex tasks with some simple scripting. Just keep in mind that there **are** limits put in place to prevent abuse/spamming.

Answer (score 0):

But it'S possible - you need to search the script gallery in Google docs.

I use a script called TTResponse and it works fine.

Another, 'Formemailer' is more complex, but also works. It runs on Javascript.

Comment: Can you link to it?

Comment: My bad - it's called 'TTRresponds', but it seems I can't link to it. Sorry! Reach it via the script gallery in 'Insert - Script'

Comment: The script gallery is not available anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Check the messaging functions in the 'tools' menu if you want to be notified of changes to your form,

Comment: Could you add some screenshots or exact steps to your answer?

Comment: I'll try…Bit busy at the moment, will take a look later